# Prove that discrete first hitting time is a stopping time

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

I have problems with the proof that a first hitting time is a stopping time:

Let $\tau$ be the first hitting time into the set A, for a process $\{ X_n \}$ adapted to a filtration $\mathcal F_n$.

I know that a random time is a stopping time if the set $ \{\tau\le n\}\in\mathcal F_n   \, \, \forall n \in[0,\infty)$

Define now the first hitting time as  $\tau_A= \mathrm{inf}(n\ge0 : X_n\in A)$

I find everywhere the same proof:

$ \{\omega \in \Omega : \tau_A(\omega) \le n\} =\bigcup_{k=0}^n\{\omega \in \Omega : X_k(\omega) \in A\} \in \mathcal F_n$

Comment: Go back wayyyy behind, to the first chapter of notational conventions in probability theory: there, they say that $ \{\tau_A \le n\}$ is a shorthand for the set $$ \{\omega\in\Omega\,|\,\tau_A(\omega) \le n\}.$$ If this point is clear to you, you should also be able to correct the definition of $\tau_A$ in your post, which is absurd at the moment since it confuses $ \tau_A$ with $ \{\tau_A\}$.

Comment: $\tau$ is random variable so it takes as argument $\omega$ and I agree, but in a practical example what could be an $\omega$ in this case? for r.v. which are like "n° of heads in 2 coins tosses" a possible $\omega=\{HT\}$. I imagine that also the notation $\{X_k\in A\}$ means $\{\omega\in\Omega : X_k(\omega)\in A\}$, but again now, which could be an $\omega$ for $X_k$? I have problems in visualizing this in my head since stochastic processes for me are r.v. indexed on the time, but I never asked myself which values they take from $\Omega$ to give back the output real number.

Comment: The identity of $\Omega$ is irrelevant, all that counts is that there exists such suitable probability space. Try to solve the exercise and you will see that you never need to know what $\Omega$ is. I might even have explained this in details somewhere on the site.

Comment: If I had to explain with words the proof, I would say that the omegas for which $\tau_A(\omega)\le n$ are the same as the union of the omegas such that $X_k(\omega)\in A$ but since we are considering a sequence of $X_k$ until n, these omegas are in $\mathcal F_n$, is that correct?

Comment: No, that some $\omega$ is or is not in $\mathcal F_n$ is far from being correct. What is the nature of the object $\mathcal F_n$, already?

Comment: $\mathcal F_n$ is the information we have until n because it's a collection of sigma-algebras $\mathcal F_1,...\mathcal F_n\subset \mathcal F$ with $\mathcal F$ the sigma-algebra of our probability space. But I said that $\omega$ is in $\mathcal F_n$, not "is or is not", otherwise I didn't understand what you meant with "is or is not"

Comment: No, $\mathcal F_n$ is not a collection of sub-algebras, it is a (single) sub-algebra. As such, to assert that some given $\omega$ in $\Omega$ is or is not in $\mathcal F_n$ is meaningless.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filtration_(mathematics)#Measure_theory a filtration is a collection of sigma-algebras.

Comment: ?? Would you be confusing $F_n$ and $(F_n)_{n/ge0}$, by any chance? And once again, "$\omega$ is in $F_n$" would be meaningful if $F_n$ was a subset of $\Omega$. It is not.

Comment: I never encountered $(F_n)_{n/ge()}$, I would say that the second set in the proof is in $\mathcal F_n$ because $X_k,k=0,...,n$ is $\mathcal F_n$ measurable, but still I am not so convinced that the first equation holds. Otherwise would you please explain to me with words why the proof holds in its 2 steps?

Comment: That $$ \{\omega \in \Omega : \tau_A(\omega) \le n\} =\bigcup_{k=0}^n\{\omega \in \Omega : X_k(\omega) \in A\},$$ you mean? Well, aint'it straightforward from the definition of $\tau_A$ as  $\tau_A(\omega)= \inf(n\ge0 : X_n(\omega)\in A)$?

Comment: No, it's not straightforward to me, for example, why do I have to take the union? and also was correct to say that the last step holds because  because $X_k,k=0,...,n$ is $\mathcal F_n$ measurable?

Comment: Yes the union on the RHS of the identity in my last comment is in $F_n$ because every $X_k$ with $k\le n$ is $F_n$-measurable. About the fact that the identity itself holds, how would you write down the event $\{\tau_A\le n\}$ in terms of the random variables $(X_k)$? Say, $\{\tau_A\le1\}$?

Comment: let me first try with event $\{\tau_A=n\}=\{X_n\in A\}$, or also $\{\tau_A=n-1\}=\{X_{n-1}\in A\}$ if that's correct, I can understand the union

Comment: About $\{\tau_A\le 1\}=\{X_0\in A\}\bigcup \{X_1\in A\}$

Comment: Actually, $\{\tau_A=n\}\ne\{X_n\in A\}$ (except if $n=0$) and yes, $\{\tau_A\le1\}=\{X_0\in A\}\cup\{X_1\in A\}$. All of this should enable you to solve the exercise.

Comment: to know what is $\{\tau_A=n \}$ I try with $\{\tau_A=2\}=\{X_0\notin A\}\bigcup \{X_1\notin A\}\bigcup \{X_2\in A\}$

Comment: What happens if $X_0\in A$ and $X_1\in A$? Do you think that, then, $\tau_A=1$?

Comment: sorry I just modified my comment before reading your reply may you please check it? It's something like that but I need the intersection maybe

Comment: For $\{\tau_A=2\}$ I need a set which contains all the omegas such that X enters A for the first time only at 2. I am also trying to understand why $\{\tau_A=\infty \}=\bigcap_k\{X_k\notin A\}$

Comment: I think that if you understand the formula below, the rest should follow (and I see no reason why you should not understand it, and this thread is already too long, so this is my last comment here): $$\{\tau_A=2\}=\{X_0\notin A\}\cap\{X_1\notin A\}\cap\{X_2\in A\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

So I then got the answer:

$\{\tau_A\le n\}=\bigcup_{k=0}^n \{X_k\in A\}
$ because if the first hitting time of A has occurred before n, the omegas for which this occur are the same omegas for $X_k$ for which "At least a $X_k$ at some point before n has entered A", then these omegas belong to $\mathcal F_n$ because $X_k$ is $\mathcal F_n$-measurable.

Comment: $\{\bigcup_{k=0}^n X_k\in A\}$: incorrect notation.

Comment: do I have to write $\bigcup _{k=0}^n\{X_k\in A\}$ ?

Comment: You have. $ $ $ $